# DoesNotExist at /delete/4/ Employee matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

When I'm deleting from the Patient table I'm getting this error:

```
DoesNotExist at /delete/4/
Employee matching query does not exist.
```

views.py

```
def delete_emp(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pi = Employee.objects.get(id=pk)
        pi.delete()
        return redirect('/employee')

def delete_pat(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pi = Patient.objects.get(id=pk)
        pi.delete()
        return redirect('/patient')
```

this is html page:

```
<td>
        <form action="{% url 'home:delete_pat' p.id %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Delete">
        </form>
      </td>
```

models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=17,default='')
    age=models.IntegerField(default='')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    doctor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='homes'),
    path('add/<int:pk>/', addqty, name='add'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/',EditProdView.as_view(), name='edit'),
    path('supedit/<int:pk>/',EditSupplierView.as_view(), name='supedit'),
    path('createemployee/', views.CreateEmployeeView, name='create-employee'),
    path('createpatient/', views.CreatePatientView, name='create-patient'),

    path('empedit/<int:pk>/',EditEmployeeView.as_view(), name='empedit'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete_emp, name='delete_emp'),

    path('patedit/<int:pk>/',EditPatientView.as_view(), name='patedit'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete_pat, name='delete_pat'),

    path('employee/', views.employees, name='employee-list'),
    path('patient/', views.patients, name='patient-list'),

]
```

Please, can anyone help me to get out of this, any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Looks like you don't have a patient with `id == 4`... '

Comment: can you share your full template ?

Comment: I wonder why the error says "Employee matching..." when you are deleting a patient?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use filter, so it doesn't throw an error like ****matching query does not** exist**

example:

```
def delete_emp(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pi = Employee.objects.filter(id=pk).fisrt()
        if pi:
            pi.delete()
        return redirect('/employee')
```

Comment: That's not a great solution - OP shouldn't be displaying delete buttons for records that don't exist!

Comment: Thank you, now this is not throwing any error but whenever I delete a patient it will redirect to the employee page. I don't know-how.

Comment: you have a return redirect that's why

Comment: So what should I do.

Comment: it's depend upon your logic where you want to redirect

Comment: I want to redirect to the same page.

Comment: share urls.py file

Comment: I have added my urls.py

Comment: you redirect your view here?

path('employee/', views.employees, name='employee-list'),

Answer (score 2):

You have used two similar url for both your functions, that is why you are raising that error. Change your employee url, so your patient will work.
In your case it is:

```
path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete_pat, name='delete_pat'),
path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete_emp, name='delete_emp'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work for you :

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def delete_emp(request, pk):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      try:       
         pi = Employee.objects.get(id=pk)
         pi.delete()
      except ObjectDoesNotExist:
         print(f"Record is not found with the id: {pk}")
      return redirect('/employee')
```